# Warning: flattenChildren(...) with react-native Navigator and DrawerLayoutAndroid

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I get the following warning every time i hit the same item in the drawer twice:

```
Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `scene_1`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.
```

Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
    View, Navigator,DrawerLayoutAndroid, Text, TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

const ROUTES = [ { name: 'Main' } ];

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <DrawerLayoutAndroid
                    ref="drawer"
                    drawerWidth={300}
                    renderNavigationView={() => (
                        <View>
                            <TouchableHighlight
                                key={ROUTES[0].name}
                                onPress={() => this.refs.navigator.push(ROUTES[0])}
                            >
                                <Text>{ROUTES[0].name}</Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </View>
                    )}
                >
                    <Navigator
                        ref="navigator"
                        initialRoute={ROUTES[0]}
                        renderScene={route => <Text>Scene {route.name}</Text>}
                    />
                </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Currently i don't know how do deal with this. This warning also looks very common for different problems.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, using `this.refs.navigator.replace(...)` instead of `this.refs.navigator.push(...)` will solve the problem.

Comment: How you found the solution? I'm facing the same issue on ios... And replace instead of push is not a solution...

Comment: Maybe it's not a real solution. But it solved the problem in my case. I found this by reading the docs. Maybe I do not understand the concept behind the navigator part. What my first time working with it. Good luck finding a solution on your problem. :)

Comment: I've posted my problem there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730072/issue-when-pushing-new-route-with-navigator and found the solution since. This error happens when you try to push the same route twice to the navigator stack. It's also what happens in your case. You have a single route and you push it to the route stack again...

Answer (score 0):

Just for other people that might get the same issue: this error happens when you try to push a route that is already in the Navigator stack. That is forbidden. In that case, better push a new route with the same component or replace the last route if it is the one subject to duplication.