# Issue when pushing new route with Navigator

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm having a strange behavior with `Navigator`. The first time I will call `navigator.push(...)`, it will sometimes print the following warning:

```
Warning: flattenChildren(...): two children with the same key, 'scene_1'. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.
  in RTCView (created by View)
  in View (created by Navigator)
```

Or, it will display a blank page.

However, if I pop and push again, it will work... What's happening?

---

Edit:

Here was the code:

```
import Page1 from '../page/Page1';
import Page2 from '../page/Page2';
import Page3 from '../page/Page3';

const routes = [
    { index: 0, title: 'Page 1' , component: Page1 },
    { index: 1, title: 'Page 2', component: Page2 },
    { index: 2, title: 'Page 3', component: Page3 },
];

class MyApp extends Component {

    renderScene(route, navigator) {

        let Component = route.component ;

        if (route.component) {
            return (
                <Component navigator={ navigator } />
            );
        }
        return null;
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <Navigator
                initialRoute={ routes[0] }
                initialRouteStack={ routes }
                renderScene={ this.renderScene } 
            />
        );
    }
}
```

=> I've just tried to remove the `initialRouteStack` prop from the Navigator and it seems to have solved my issue. I however do not understand what is this prop used for...

Comment: Do you mind showing your Navigator code (initial route and render scene) as well as the push method that is sometimes breaking?

Comment: Yes, let me edit the issue. I also just might have found the solution...

Comment: I honestly don't know for sure the scenario when `initialRouteStack` is necessary, so I think that was a good move. I've built multiple apps without needing to implement an initial route stack.

Answer (score 1):

initialRouteStack is the stack you're giving the navigator to begin with. Normally you just pass an initialRoute, so you're stack will start with just that route.

But you were passing all the routes into the initialRouteStack, so when you navigated to another scene you were basically pushing components to the end of that stack which already contains that component. Hope this makes sense and clarifies things.